# Can I make GhostScript use more than 2 GB of RAM?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I'm running a 64-bit version of GhostScript (9.50) on 64-bit processor with 16gb of RAM under Windows 7.

GhostScript returns a random-ish error message (it will tell me that I have type error in the array command) when I try to allocate one too many arrays totaling more than 2 GBs of RAM.

To be clear, I am seeing how  growth of the memory usage in Windows Task Monitor, not from within GhostScript

I'd like to know why this is so.

More importantly, I'd like to know if I can override this behavior.

Edit: This code produces the error --

```
/TL 25000 def 
/TL- TL 1 sub def 
/G TL array def
0 1 TL- { dup == flush G exch TL array put }for
```

The error looks like this: Here's the last bit of the messages I get

```
5335 
5336 
5337 
5338 
5339 
5340 
5341 
5342 
5343 
5344 
5345 
Unrecoverable error: typecheck in array 
Operand stack: --nostringval-- --- 
Begin offending input --- 
/TL 25000 def /TL- TL 1 sub def /G TL array def 0 1 TL- { dup == flush G exch TL array put }for --- End offending input --- file offset = 0 gsapi_run_string_continue returns -20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of RAM is almost certainly not the limiting factor, but it would help if you were to post the actual error message. It may be 'random-ish' to you, but it's meaningful to people who program in PostScript.

More than likely you've tripped over some other internal limit, for example the operand stack size but without seeing the PostScript program or the error message I cannot say any more than that. I can say that (64-bit) Ghostscript will happily address more than 2GB of RAM, I was running a file last week which had Ghostscript using 8.1GB.

Note that PostScript itself is basically a 32-bit language; while Ghostscript has extended many of the architectural limitations documented in the PostScript Language Reference Manual (such as 64K elements in arrays and strings) moving beyond 32-bit limits is essentially unspecified.

As to whether you can change the behaviour, that depends on **exactly** what the problem is, and I can't tell from what's here.

### Edit

Here's a screenshot of Ghostscript running the test file to completion, along with the Task Manager display showing the amount of memory the process is using. Not shown is the vmstatus which I ran from the PostScript environment afterwards. This showed that Ghostscript thinks it's using 10,010,729,850 bytes form a maximum of 10,012,037,312. My calculator says that 9,562.8MB comes out at 10,027,322,572.4 bytes, so a pretty close match.

To answer the points in the comments this is (as you can probably tell) on a 64-bit Windows 10 installation with quite a lot of memory.

The difference is, almost certainly, something which has been fixed since the release of 9.52. The 9.52 64-bit binary does exit with a VMerror after (for me) 5360 iterations. Obviously trying to use vast amounts of **PostScript** memory (as opposed to, say, canvas memory) is not a common occurrence, not least because many PostScript interpreters simply won't allow it,  so this doesn't get exercised much.

The Ghostscript Git repository is [here](https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=summary) if you want to go through the commits and try to figure out which one caused the change. You only have to go back to March this year, anything before about the 19th March would have been in 9.52.

Beyond simple curiosity, is there a reason to try and use up loads of memory in PostScript ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry - I called the error message "random-ish" despite its clarity, but rather because it's just false:  as the message indicates, GhostScript executed "array" without a type error 5345 times, but the exact same code failed on the 5345th attempt.   I got a screenshot of the Windows Task Monitor a couple of seconds before the error, and this process was using 2,099,600 kb.  Another screenshot makes it clear that I had 5gb of RAM to spare.

Comment: I'm running GhostScript here with GhostView's default command line.

Comment: The message won;t be false, but it could be triggered by something you don't expect. For example if you exhaust an internal limit that might return limitcheck. Or a higher level piece of processing may turn errors from a lower level piece of code into a different kind of error. I've no idea what you mean by GhostView's default command line, I don't think it has one per se. The commaned line depends on what you are doing (eg PDF or PostScript or EPS, display, rendering to image file, printing...). I'm afraid without seeing the PostScript program, and a command line I can't really offer any help

Comment: Umm, you know you should really be editing your question, rather than my answer ? :-)

Comment: Using the code you suggested editing into my answer, a 64-bit debug build of the current 9.53.0 Release Candidate, and a command line of "gswin64c test.ps" I'm currently up to iteration 7264 with a committed memory allocation of 2,795.0 MB according to Task Manager, and still climbing. I may not have enough time to let it finish as this stresses the (Ghostscript) memory manager, so its slow.

Comment: Its up to iteration 9007 and memory consumed is 3,461.0MB at which point I've got to kill it because I'm off for the night. You should probably try current code and if that doesn't work you'll need to tell me exactly how you are driving Ghostscript.

Comment: Sorry about editing the wrong place.  I didn't even realize I *could* do that.  Fixed.
Thank you.  I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: KenS  Tried it like you said, from a command line, avoiding GhostView.  I got similar behavior but a different error message.  It looks like \\
GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19) \\
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved. 
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
0
1
2
.
.
.
5359
5360 
Error: /VMerror in /----nostringval---- \\
VM status: 1 2148270810 2149560304 \\
Current allocation mode is local  \\
Current file position is 101 \\
Unrecoverable error: VMerror in ----nostringval----

Comment: Same behavior, by the way, if I run the Command Prompt window as administrator.

Comment: GhostView, under Advanced Configure, allows one to set GhostScript Options.  By default, they are...-dNOPLATFONTS -sFONTPATH="c:\psfonts"

Comment: OK so the Ghostview options there are not 'the default command line' they are default **additions** to the command line. I'm using current HEAD from the GhostScript Git repository and I just built a new release binary which I'm running. The next release of Ghostscript, 9.53.0 is due this week unless something pops up in the next day or two. Note the addition of a patch level in this release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221131/discussion-between-david-feldman-and-kens).

Comment: Thank you KenS.  Should I understand that your asserting that (you expect) that the difference between my experience and yours is the difference between 9.52 and 9.53?
I said I'm running Windows 7.  Professional, to be precise.  You never said what version of Windows or even whether your running under Windows at all.  Could my problem be with the OS and not with GhostScript at all?

Comment: >Beyond simple curiosity, is there a reason to try and use up loads of memory in PostScript ?
I'm a digital artist and PostScript is my main platform.  So I also use it as a general purpose language, especially for one-off projects, where I care more about time spent coding than speed of execution.  In this case, I needed to do a combinatorial search for a music-theory resource and it would have speeded up things to precompute a 25000x25000 matrix.  But have come to this wall many times with other projects though, so I figured it was time to ask what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Well, 9.53.0 is due for release this week, so you should be able to use that. Though you'll probably have to use Ghostscript, I doubt many other PostScript interpreters will be able to address the kind of memory needed. Also you'll need a lot of RAM! best part of 10GB was used by the array of arrays here.

Comment: Thanks!  I've never used any other interpreter...and I have lots and lots of RAM.  So I'm good.  I do like stack-oriented programming...used to do Forth years ago.  So sometimes even when I make art with PostScript I don't even use the graphics commands.  I'll just make a big array of pixels, compute the colors and finally output to a PPM file.  And it will be just great soon to have no limit on resolution beyond the amount of RAM.